# disable pytest plugin terminalreporter via conftest?

Tags: python, pytest

Is there a programmatic equivalent (i.e. conftest.py) to setting `-p no:terminal` in pytest?

I know it's possible to add it to the `addopts` in pytest.ini.  But ultimately I would like to be able to have one plugin disable or prevent another plugin from loading.

In my case, my plugin would replace terminalreporter entirely.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible via pytest hooks. Here's an example from [my own plugin](https://github.com/Tbruno25/pytest-timestamps/blob/7b0453c5fc5106cf34ee26857d14ac57cbf10ab1/pytest_timestamps/plugin.py#L49)

```
@pytest.hookimpl(trylast=True)
def pytest_configure(config):
    if config.pluginmanager.has_plugin("terminalreporter"):
        reporter = config.pluginmanager.get_plugin("terminalreporter")
        config.pluginmanager.unregister(reporter, "terminalreporter")
        config.pluginmanager.register(<New_Terminal_Reporter>, "terminalreporter")
```